# Is Singleton in asp.net session specific or one for all sessions?

Tags: asp.net, .net, singleton

I am wondering, is a singleton in asp.net session specific or is it shared between all user sessions?

Also does it remain alive until application is restarted, when a user session ends or when garbage collecting starts and clears memory from it as well.

Your input is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the code of your singleton? There are multiple ways to write one, and it may affect the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A traditional singleton - with a reference in a static variable - will live for as long as the AppDomain lives. It will *not* be session-oriented. It will be garbage collected when the AppDomain is recycled (or the app is shut down).

Comment: does it means singleton can be used in asp.net to share data or methods across all user sessions ? Does it look a good approach ?

Comment: just a thought may be for reading configurations or error logging. Can it be used to be shared across all user sessions. I understand it is not a persistent memory though.

Comment: @user576510: It's *potentially* reasonable for cached data, although I'd actually approach it in a different way, using dependency injection to inject an instance of a class where there *happened* to be only one shared instance, rather than making it a *forced* singleton. That would be easier to test. (I'm not a fan of singletons, in general.)

Comment: @user576510 A classical singleton used by all sessions in ASP.NET needs to preferably be immutable or at the very least thread safe. If you're not confident how to approach that, it may not be the best approach. You should also keep in mind that if you scale to two servers, your singleton will suddenly be _two_ separate singletons.

Comment: @JonSkeet I got your point, but can you please share any situations where you used singleton, where singleton was the solution ?

In web context we have Cashing available to use. Does it mean in asp.net there is no space for singleton ?

Comment: @user576510: It's been a long time since I've used a true singleton, to be honest.